# Univariate clustering for longitudinal cohort

Tags: time-series, clustering, panel-data, unsupervised-learning

We have screening information on thousands of patients followed for several years. We also have their cancer outcomes, whether or not such cancers were identified by screening or were otherwise symptomatic. Exogenous to that question is the question of how people screen. It's a tough question, in general, since there are several factors determining how/why/when people screen. Relevant to that is the idea of predicting *when* a given individual will screen conditional upon their screening history.

Usually, rates are the only measure used to characterize such patterns. That is done by calculating a total risk time denominator. But it may be more complex than that. As we know, processes which determine interarrival times can be quite complex indeed. Whether they are dependent, or approximately Markov is important. Additionally, we would like to know what the shape of the density of interarrival times is and whether there are common distinguishing characteristics, such as bimodality in those data.

However a parametric approach can be quite limited indeed. And structurally testing assumptions while building sophisticated enough models to determine differences seems like it would greatly increase the type 1 error. Is there a general Markov model or unsupervised learning approach that can be used to identify clusters of times series that are distinct from one another in a more general fashion than rates?